# Split overlapping and add missing intervals

Tags: java, intervals

I have a set of [startdate,enddate] intervals which can be overlapping and contain gaps. 
My goal is to have a continuous new list of intervals, without gaps and without any overlapping dates.

Example of ranges:

```
[-----------------------------------A-----------------------]
[-B]
   [-C]
      [D]
                  [-----E-----]
                              [-----F----]
                                                                    [-----G-----]                

A [2009-01-01 - 2014-01-01]     ~5 years
B [2009-01-01 - 2009-01-02]     2 days
C [2009-01-02 - 2009-01-03]     2 days
D [2009-01-04 - 2009-01-04]     1 day
E [2010-01-01 - 2011-01-01]     ~1 year
F [2011-01-01 - 2012-01-01]     ~1 year, a gap after this interval
G [2015-01-01 - 2016-01-01]     ~1 year
```

What I expect is this new list of intervals:

```
[2009-01-01 - 2009-01-01]
[2009-01-02 - 2009-01-02]
[2009-01-03 - 2009-01-03]
[2009-01-04 - 2009-01-04]
[2009-01-05 - 2009-12-31]
[2010-01-01 - 2010-12-31]
[2011-01-01 - 2012-01-01]
[2012-01-02 - 2014-01-01]
[2014-01-02 - 2014-12-31]
[2015-01-01 - 2016-01-01]
```

So, for gaps there are new intervals added. Intervals with the same startdate and enddate are perfectly valid and should be handled as such.

I am quite stuck on both the best way to achieve this, even before getting this in an efficient way :(

Any ideas on how to perform this in Java?

Comment: If you use java8 you can use the java.time.Period. Then sort all periods and compare start/end of two consecutive periods.

Comment: @Heri No, a `Period` has neither start nor end (not anchored on the date line). The OP needs an interval solution instead.

Comment: Period offers a lot of operations you can use to solve your problem: between() constructs it by taking two LocalDate's. With addTo() and subtractFrom() you can do your calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the [range-package](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/package-summary.html) of my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) and use this code:

```
DateInterval a = DateInterval.between(PlainDate.of(2009, 1, 1), PlainDate.of(2014, 1, 1));
DateInterval b = DateInterval.between(PlainDate.of(2009, 1, 1), PlainDate.of(2009, 1, 2));
DateInterval c = DateInterval.between(PlainDate.of(2009, 1, 2), PlainDate.of(2009, 1, 3));
DateInterval d = DateInterval.between(PlainDate.of(2009, 1, 4), PlainDate.of(2009, 1, 4));
DateInterval e = DateInterval.between(PlainDate.of(2010, 1, 1), PlainDate.of(2011, 1, 1));
DateInterval f = DateInterval.between(PlainDate.of(2011, 1, 1), PlainDate.of(2012, 1, 1));
DateInterval g = DateInterval.between(PlainDate.of(2015, 1, 1), PlainDate.of(2016, 1, 1));

List<DateInterval> intervals = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);

IntervalCollection<PlainDate> icoll = IntervalCollection.onDateAxis().plus(intervals);

for (ChronoInterval<PlainDate> gap : icoll.withGaps().getIntervals()) {
    icoll = icoll.plus(gap);
}

System.out.println(icoll.withSplits());

[2009-01-01/2009-01-01],
[2009-01-02/2009-01-02],
[2009-01-03/2009-01-03],
[2009-01-04/2009-01-04],
[2009-01-05/2009-12-31],
[2010-01-01/2010-12-31],
[2011-01-01/2011-01-01],
[2011-01-02/2012-01-01],
[2012-01-02/2014-01-01],
[2014-01-02/2014-12-31],
[2015-01-01/2016-01-01]
```

**Remark about your expected results:**

Your statement

> My goal is to have a continuous new list of intervals, without gaps
>   and without any overlapping dates.

is realized with the code above. The gaps are added as normal intervals to the whole interval collection before splitting. All date intervals in Time4J are handled as closed intervals by default (configurable). That means for example that an interval like "[2009-01-01/2009-01-01]" consists of only one day (as you also have shown in the first entry of your expected interval list).

However, you didn't seem to expect the interval "[2011-01-01/2011-01-01]", but just this date (interval consisting of only one day) is an overlapping region between intervals E + F and should also appear in your expected interval list.

**About interoperability with Java-8:**

You can also apply direct conversion methods like [toTemporalAccessor()](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainDate.html#toTemporalAccessor--) or [from(LocalDate)](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainDate.html#from-java.time.LocalDate-) between the types `net.time4j.PlainDate` and `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. And yes, you are right about the missing interval. :)

Comment: The square brackets produced by `toString()` shown above indicate closed interval boundaries (standard for date intervals). Anyway, you can also choose your own customized interval formats, see the API-methods like [print](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IsoInterval.html#print-net.time4j.format.expert.ChronoPrinter-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

First, sort them all by start date.

Then iterate them, and all of the following to comparing each with the next:

- If `curr.end >= next.start` then `curr.end = next.start - 1`
- If `curr.end < curr.start` then remove it
- If `curr.end < next.start - 1` then add new with:

  ```
  new.start = curr.end + 1
  new.end = next.start - 1
  ```

Also keep track of max end date (before updates), and if `max(end) > last.end` then add new with:

```
new.start = last.end + 1
new.end = max(end)
```